# The easiest way in Rails to find the project with the most user tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm still pretty green when it comes to Rails and I'm trying to create a scope or class method to help me get the "Most active project" in my timetracking app where:

A task belongs to project and user.

I can access user.tasks and project.tasks as well as finding out the number of hours on each project using the class method on project.rb

```
def project_hours
  tasks.sum(:hours)
end
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to perform a query to get all tasks that were performed for project A by user B

and then as a follow up, try and order projects by the amount of task hours for this project by this user.

I apologise if this has been covered before, I'm not sure if there is an effective way of achieving this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model:

```
def tasks_by_project(project)
    self.tasks.where({:project_id => project.id}).group('tasks.project_id').order('SUM(tasks.hours) ASC')
end
```

Now you can do

```
@user = User.find(1)
@project = Project.find(232)

# return a list of projects scoped by user_id andproject id, ordered by task hours
@user.tasks_by_project(@project)
```

Comment: Thanks Venice that's great and has got me the tasks by user and project. Now I'm trying to figure out how (if possible) to order the projects themselves by task hours rather than ordering the task themselves?

Comment: In my example I included a group() and order() method. Does that work correctly? It should order by the sum of hours, grouped by the task hours of a project.

Comment: Thanks Venice, it seemed to be spitting out a group os tasks so I could call .first or .last and it would be a single task but ideally I was looking to group the projects not the tasks within them. 

I've now run into another issue as I've had to switch to Postgres and it seems this method uses incompatible syntax.